# set html lang value on flask

Tags: flask, wtforms

I would like to find a way to set the `<html lang='en'>` attribute value. Right now the root html template is being extracted from the flask libraries `{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}`

I don't wanna set that setting using javascript. Know any way to help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer:

```
{% block html_attribs %}lang="en"{% endblock %}
```

reference: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html